# What reason might be that mobile device is not registered with OneSignal?

Tags: javascript, react-native, onesignal

We have a small app that we started alpha testing yesterday with among roughly 50 people. It's React Native app. There are push notifications handled by OneSignal and these are kinda essential to get most out of the app. For like 80% of people it's working just fine. Their device gets registered, I store userId in our database and notification is sent and received. For others, I am not even able to get userId.

All users have the exact same app, there are no variants, so OneSignal appId is definitely correct there.

I have the following code that's executed whenever the app is started. For those failing users the `registerOneSignal` function is not even called. It's really strange behavior. Could be a bug in OneSignal?

> react-native-onesignal: v3.0.5

```
const alternateApproach = (device) => {
  log.debug('onesignal ids', device)
  this.activateOneSignal(device.userId, device)
}

const registerOneSignal = (status: SubscriptionStatus) => {
  log.debug('onesignal state', status)
  if (!status.userId) {
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', alternateApproach)
    return
  }
  this.activateOneSignal(status.userId)
}

OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState(registerOnesignal)
```

Comment: If your `registerOnesignal` is not being called then it means that `OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState` fails for some reason. Maybe there is weak Internet connection or may actually be a bug. I think the best thing to do is to contact OneSignal's support.

Comment: I went through the hell of debugging this on a production code. However, I can now confirm, that `registerOneSignal` is called, but the actual callback from `getPermissionSubscriptionState` is never invoked. I guess contacting support is only remaining option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was indeed a mistake on my side simply coming from the fact, that when an event is fired before the listener is attached, it will be missed forever. I have moved listening for `ids` event to a very early point in my app and it seems to be working for everyone now.

What's bit strange though, that `OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState` is not an event, it should invoke a callback to get data out of it no matter timing. So apparently there is some bug in OneSignal module. Perhaps there is an event underneath too? I've moved the call of this method to the same point I am listening for `ids`. Doing a couple of tests it indeed shows that `ids` is called every time, but the callback for that method is never invoked in some cases.